# folder structure for serverless framework handlers

Tags: serverless-framework

So I am working on a serverless framework project( and am fairly new to it ) and I am struggling to choose a folder structure for my lambda handlers.

for example, say I have a "user" path and I want to do CRUD operations for users.
in my project directory I would have the following:

- serverless.yml
- src/users/index.js

the index.js would contain all of the handlers: e.g.
`module.exports = {createUser,updateUser,deleteUser,getUser}`

the alternative would be to use a folder structure with the following:

- serverless.yml
- src/users/createUser/handler.js
- src/users/updateUser/handler.js
- src/users/deleteUser/handler.js
- src/users/getUser/handler.js

are there any implications of using the first approach in comparison to second approach when deploying the serverless application?

note: the first approach is not using a mono function , rather just having all the handlers for the path inside that one module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using a mono-lambda API pattern, then I suggest grouping files by function - which in this case is the first option you listed, along with specifying individual function packaging with:

```
package:
  individually: true
```

in your `serverless.yml` template. This ensures that only the code needed by a specific REST resource is included in that function.

If you want to learn more about the tradeoffs and differences of a mono-lambda API vs a single-function API, you can read my [post](https://dev.to/aws-builders/the-what-why-and-when-of-mono-lambda-vs-single-function-apis-5cig).

Comment: hey thanks , I gave your post a read and found it informative. I decided to go with your first option , however I left out the package: individually because it just makes my deployment bloated because it recreates the same file/module( with the multiple handlers ). Would the package individually aspect be used for multiple files with ,say, one handler in it ?

Comment: When you package individually, only the files needed for a given function will be included in the uploaded function package. When you package normally, all the code for all functions is uploaded to each function. You can read more about the difference here https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/packaging